# Use pd.DataFrame.style.apply() function to apply number format to different items

Tags: python, pandas, format, apply

I am trying to apply different number format to different items in a dataframe. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Define formatting functions
def float1(x):
    return "{:.1f}".format(x)

def float2(x):
    return "{:.2f}".format(x)

def float3(x):
    return "{:.3f}".format(x)


# Sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [10.123, 20.345, 30.567],
    'B': [40.789, 50.901, 60.123],
    'C': [float1, float2, float3],
    'D': ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
})

format_dict = df['C'].to_dict()

# Apply formatting functions based on values in column C
df_styled = df.style.apply(lambda x: format_dict[x.name](x), axis=1, subset=['A', 'B'])

# Apply formatting rule to column D
df_styled = df_styled.format({'D': '{}'})

# Display the styled dataframe
display(df_styled)
```

But I got the following error message:

> TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Series.**format**

How to fix that?

Comment: It could be that `df_styled.format({'D': '{}'}` is an error because `{}` is not a valid format string. The code is a little hard to follow ... are you putting formats in functions, and then those functions in a dataframe column? And then trying to use the column values as a dictionary? And finally trying to format another column with "no format"? This seems a bit of a winding path.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks topsail for prompt response. I just figured out an solution:

```
import pandas as pd

# Define formatting functions
def float1(x):
    return "{:.1f}".format(x)

def float2(x):
    return "{:.2f}".format(x)

def float3(x):
    return "{:.3f}".format(x)


# Sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [10.123, 20.345, 30.567],
    'B': [40.789, 50.901, 60.123],
    'C': [float1, float2, float3],
    'D': ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
})

def num_format(row):
    return pd.Series([row['C'](row['A']), row['C'](row['B'])])

df_style = df.copy()
df_style[['A', 'B']] = df.apply(num_format, axis=1)
display(df_style[['A', 'B', 'D']])
```

The output is like

| A | B | D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.1 | 40.8 | string1 |
| 20.34 | 50.90 | string2 |
| 30.567 | 60.123 | string3 |